# AWS SAM Package don't send to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to send a simple hello world using net core 3.1 lambda with AWS SAM, so this is my template.yml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Net Core 3.1 Lambda
Resources:
  netcore31lambdafunc:
    Type: AWS::Serveless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: Netcore31Test
      CodeUri: src/LambdaEmptyServerless/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish
      Handler: LambdaEmptyServerless::LambdaEmptyServerless.Functions::Get
      Runtime: dotnetcore3.1
      Events:
        netcore31ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: GET
```

That is located in this level:

[image]

Now I'm trying to package this to S3 bucket, so I'm executing the following:

```
sam package --template-file template.yml --output-template-file out-template.yml  --s3-bucket demo-sam-001
```

I got the following return:

```
Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file out-template.yml.
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template
sam deploy --template-file C:\Users\rlanh\Workspace\Pessoal\awssam-netcore31\LambdaEmptyServerless\out-template.yml --stack-name <YOUR STACK NAME>
```

But nothing is uploaded to my S3 bucket.

Comment: I think you can try with: aws cloudformation package --template-file .aws-sam/build/template.yaml --s3-bucket $TEMPLATE_BUCKET --output-template-file cloudformation-packaged.yaml . It has the same output.

Comment: Now works, but why ? Should work with sam package, not ?

Comment: I'm not sure with sam package. Do you have --debug to see more information?

Comment: did you `sam build`?

Comment: yes , i did sam build.

Comment: add a `--debug` to your `sam package` to see if there is additional info we can see. Also, can you show the content of `.aws-sam/build/template.yaml`?